# Alternatives to partial controller classes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, single-responsibility-principle

I have moved onto a project that has a `public partial class AdminController`, there are 15 other classes that implement this partial class. I think this is done so the project can have lots of routes accessible via the `"/admin/{methodname}"` path.

The primary partial class handles the constructor for all 15 classes and therefore has 13 constructor dependencies.

I don't think this is very pretty but am unsure how to tidy this up so each class can have the dependencies it needs but keep all routes going to `"/admin/{methodname}"`

Comment: Could you create independant Controllers and have some logic in Routing engine, to map routes to `/admin/{methodname}`? This isn't clean either, but looks like there are a lot of admin routes in your case.

Comment: Or maybe have a hash to hold routes and routing engine does the mapping via this hash?

Comment: Could you show some code?

Comment: took a shot at an answer - its off the top of my head, didnt run the code.

Answer (score 2):

Consider converting `/admin` into an [MVC Area](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), and having different controllers handle different paths within that area.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more? Thanks

Comment: From what I can see that would mean I could tidy up the controllers but the paths would then become "/admin/{controllername}/{originalmethod}"

Comment: @Jon: First of all, is that really so bad? If you separate your controllers by their logical function, it's likely that you'll end up with sensible URLs using the "{area}/{controller}/{action}" pattern. Secondly, it should be possible to add routes that map "/admin/action" to a specific controller and action. You could either maintain a custom route list manually, or come up with a way to scan the controllers in that area and programmatically add each action to the routes list. There are a lot of options, depending on what your specific requirements are.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior - my guess is that Jon is stuck with an application whose URLs might be referenced elsewhere (say an `<a href="/Admin/Foo"/>` in another application), hence the insistence on keeping the URLs.

Answer (score 0):

I would say, refactor the logic into smaller controllers, thus sorting out your too many dependency issue and handle the routing problem by using your own route mapping.

You could have a RouteDefinition class, which contains a tuple (I said Hash before, but I figured you'd need more than 2 parameters)

```
public static class RouteDefinitions
{
    const List<Tuple<string,string,string> AdminRoutes = new List<Tuple<string,string,string>> {
        Tuple.Create("fooroute", //route
                     "foocontroller", //corresponding controller
                     "fooaction"), //corresponding action
        Tuple.Create("barroute", "barcontroller","baraction")
    };

    public static void AddRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        foreach(var adminRoute in AdminRoutes)
            routes.MapRoute(adminRoute.Item1, string.Format("Admin/{0}", adminRoute.Item1) , new { controller = adminRoute.Item2, action = adminRoute.Item3 });
    }
}
```

And then in your `Application_Start()` call it such

```
RouteDefinitions.AddRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
```

Comment: Would that work so I could keep all the original paths so that "admin/foo" and "admin/bar" would work but foo and bar were in different controllers?

Comment: The routetable contains the controller and action, so you could explicitly map a route to any action of any controller. Ex - `Admin/foo` could be mapped to `DummyController`'s `Blah` action. You would be overriding MVC convention though. Beyond a point this could bet bloated.

Comment: Yeah.I could possibly tidy up the controller classes but then the routing would be just as messy to keep the routing as they were.

Comment: True, but that is a bigger problem IMO, more at a design level. This could be better, because you've now got the bloat in one place rather than so many classes. Plus you'll probably get classes with better cohesion, and if you have tests, those will be cleaner as well.

Comment: I wonder if Attribute Routing might help, then in each controller that is not Admin controller I can define the routes and call return View("Admin/EditUser")

Comment: That should work too! I don't use attribute routing as much, just because I prefer MVC convention or a custom routing engine which makes it easier to test. But you can test attribtutes too, so that isn't really an argument, more of a preference.